# onKeyDown stackoverflowerror Android

Tags: java, android, stack-overflow

Whenever I push buttons for long periods of time (in this instance taking a screenshot with power and lower volume), my app crashes with a StackOverFlowError.

I'm pretty sure it has to deal with the fact that I tried to reduce the amount of duplicated code in my project, and I'm pretty sure I know why. I have no idea if it's fixable inside my Utilities class, or if I should just not do it. The reason I do this is because I don't want to constantly have large amounts of code for a very simple dialog.

Utilities class

```
public static boolean onKeyDown(final Activity activity, final Class<?> action, String message, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        ParseUser.logOut();
                        if (action == null) {
                            activity.onBackPressed();
                            return;
                        }
                        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, action);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        activity.startActivity(intent);
                        break;

                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
            builder.setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener).setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
            return true;
        }
        return activity.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

And how I call it:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return Utilities.onKeyDown(this, null, "Do you want to exit the application", keyCode, event);
}
```

The log cat constantly alternates these lines:

```
at com.x.y.Login.onKeyDown(Login.java:187)
com.x.y.Utilities.onKeyDown(Utilities.java:45)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution:

Utilities.java

```
/**
 *  @return true if keyEvent is consumed
 */
public static boolean onKeyDown(final Activity activity, final Class<?> action, String message, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {

        //...all you code here

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Login.java

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(Utilities.onKeyDown(this, null, "Do you want to exit the application", keyCode, event)){
         return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: This worked :D thanks. Can you explain a little bit why? Is it because if it's true it's waiting for another event until false? "Continue to propogate" inside the documentation is what I'm assuming causes it"

Comment: It was because you call one method from another and the second one calls the first. You can return true instead of false, but you shouldn't call activity.onKeyDown(..) because you've overridden it, and call in it this function again. So you get a loop)